# Confused regarding explanation of Schumachers compression in N&C

Tags: quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang

On page 547 of N&C, for $|\psi_{0}\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $|\psi_{1}\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and for $|\tilde{0}\rangle=\cos(\pi/8)|0\rangle+\sin(\pi/8)|1\rangle$ and $|\tilde{1}\rangle=-\sin(\pi/8)|0\rangle + \cos(\pi/8)|1\rangle$, that $|\langle\tilde{0}|\psi_{k}\rangle| = \cos(\pi/8)$ and $|\langle\tilde{1}|\psi_{k}\rangle| = \sin(\pi/8)$ for k = $\{0,1\}$. I just don't see how this can be the case for either of them.

I get $\cos(\pi/8)$ and $\cos(\pi/8)/\sqrt{2}+\sin(\pi/8)\sqrt{2}$ for $|\langle\tilde{0}|\psi_{k}\rangle|$ and for $|\langle\tilde{1}|\psi_{k}\rangle|$ I get $-\sin(\pi/8)$ and $-\sin(\pi/8)/\sqrt{2}+\cos(\pi/8)/\sqrt{2}$.

The inner product only produce these for $|\psi_{0}\rangle$. Is this a typo, and what they mean to say is that the inner product $|\langle\tilde{0}|\psi_{k}\rangle|$ is much larger than $|\langle\tilde{1}|\psi_{k}\rangle|$. But even in this case, that isn't completely true, as it's only just larger in the case of $|\langle\tilde{1}|\psi_{k}\rangle|$

For context, $|\tilde{0}\rangle$ and $|\tilde{1}\rangle$ come from the spectral decomposition of the density operator representing the source that generates $|\psi_{0}\rangle$ and $|\psi_{1}\rangle$ with probability a half for each.

What am I missing here? It seems like a simple inner product should be used but I can't get their results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a bit of algebraic trickery. Remember that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$. Thus,
$$
\cos(\pi/8)/\sqrt{2}+\sin(\pi/8)/\sqrt{2}=\cos(\pi/8)\cos(\pi/4)+\sin(\pi/8)\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4-\pi/8)=\cos(\pi/8)
$$
by the double angle formula.

Also, be careful of signs. It might be an amplitude is $\pm\sin(\pi/8)$, but when you take the modulus, that becomes $\sin(\pi/8)$.

Comment: That is...... extremely frustrating. Yeah the -sin was typo on my part, but the rest of it, I made the mistake of checking it using a calculator and forgot to convert into radians. Jesus every time I think I have something down some small part like this knocks me on my ass.